# Laravel - where clausole do not works as expected

Tags: laravel-4

I have a small search form that allow user search for his clients by `id` or by `first_name,last_name`.

In my DB `fist_name` and `last_name` are in two separate column so when I try to search client by name I need to use a query that check both the column.

Here my code:

```
//Recupero l'utente corrente
        $current_user = Auth::user()->id;

        //Preparo la query
        $query = DB::table('clients');

        //Recupero l'eventuale nome e ID di ricerca cliente
        $client_id = Input::get('client_id');
        $client_name = Input::get('client_name');

        //Controllo se devo fare una ricerca per ID
        if(  is_numeric($client_id) )
        {
            $query->where('id', '=', $client_id);
        }
        elseif( trim($client_name) != "" )
        {
            //Controllo se invece ho il nome
            $query->where('nome', 'LIKE', "%$client_name%")->orWhere('cognome', 'LIKE', "%$client_name%");
        }       

        //Recupero i clienti
        $data['clients'] = $query->where('id_agente', $current_user)->paginate(10);
```

The first `if` will check if the users select the client by `ID` while the second need to check the name and last_name.

The problem is that in the second case the last `where` is ignored and return all the result in the table that match the input, so I can see data of other users.

How can I modify my code so the `where('id_agente', $current_user)` will always considered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `elseif` section just replace the following line:

```
$query->where('nome', 'LIKE', "%$client_name%")->orWhere('cognome', 'LIKE', "%$client_name%");
```

With this:

```
$query->where(function($q) use ($client_name) {
    $q->where('nome', 'LIKE', "%$client_name%")
      ->orWhere('cognome', 'LIKE', "%$client_name%");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass a closure to `where()` in your `elseif`.

```
elseif( trim($client_name) != "" )
{
    $query->where(function($subQuery) use ($client_name){
        $subQuery->where('nome', 'LIKE', "%$client_name%");
        $subQuery->orWhere('cognome', 'LIKE', "%$client_name%");
    }};
}       

$data['clients'] = $query->where('id_agente', $current_user)->paginate(10);
```

Or.. simplify the whole script:

```
$client_id = trim(Input::get('client_id'));
$client_name = trim(Input::get('client_name'));

if(empty($client_id) && empty($client_id))
    return false;

$data['cleints'] = DB::table('clients')
->where((!empty($client_id)) ? function($q) use ($client_id){
    $q->where('id', '=', $client_id)->first();
} : function($q) use ($client_name) {
    $q->where('nome', 'LIKE', "%$client_name%");
    $q->orWhere('cognome', 'LIKE', "%$client_name%");
})->where('id_agente', Auth::user()->id)
->paginate(10);
```